# Iframe make it clickable through and image

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, publisher

I'm a publisher for an ad network I would like to know if it's possible to make the iframe clickable trough an image, so when some one click on it, the link that the ad network put on the iframe show up like a pop-under, like if some one has clicked on it... 
I tried with: `<span></span>` or `<div></div>` but the image is not clickable...

Comment: And you really think we are going to help you with that?

Comment: You need to clarify your question and provide some example code please because I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

ya, check out the jquery .click() method.

it would look something like this.

```
$('img').click(function(){

    $('div.link').show();

};
```

basically, your applying the click "event handler" to a part of your document, and then triggering a function to occur when it is clicked.

good luck

[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com) - a link for further research.

Comment: I'm completly newbie, so please do you mind to reexplain it, So this the iframe `<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=476 height=216 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=http://adserver.xxxxxxxx.com/adshow.php?adzone=133938></iframe>` so where should I place it in your code, where should I place the image link and what should I do to make it show up like a pop-under when someone click on my page? Also i'm running a blog so I can only use HTML and CSS @bwheeler96 @imakeitpretty